# Tuning Storm-Crawler to fully use available resources

Tags: web-crawler, stormcrawler

I have a node fully dedicated to my Storm-Crawler based crawler. I have at disposal 20 dual-core CPUs, 130 Gb of RAM and 10Gb/s Ethernet connection.

I reduced my topology to: CollapsingSpout -> URLPartitionerBolt -> FetcherBolt. The spout is reading from an Elasticsearch index (with ~50 M records). Elasticsearch is configured with 30 GB RAM and 2 shards.

I use a single worker with roughly 50 GB of RAM dedicated to the JVM.
Playing with the different settings (total number of threads, number of threads per queue, max pending spout, some related to Elasticsearch such as number of buckets and bucket size mainly) I can reach an overall fetching speed of 100 MB/s. However, looking at ganglia reports, it corresponds to only 10% of the bandwidth available to me. Note that CPU usage is at about 20% and RAM is not an issue.

I’m seeking some hints on what could be my bottleneck and advice on how to tune/adjust my crawler to fully use the resources available to me.

Thanks in advance.

Etienne

Comment: Hi Etienne. How many sites are you crawling?  See http://stormcrawler.net/faq/#howfast

Comment: Hi Julien. I don't know how many sites I'm crawling. I'm using a pool of 50 M urls stemming from a previous recursive crawl. And for the tuning I have removed all sleep times. After some more trials I could reach 200 MB/s network usage, but overall I'm still using at most only 20% of the machine's resources.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Kibana or Grafana to visualise the metrics generated by StormCrawler, see [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KTerugU12TY&t=2s). This would give you some insights into the performance. Also, the Storm UI will tell you of bottlenecks at the component level.

You could use more than 2 shards for the status index and have the corresponding number of spout instances. This would increase the parallelism.

Do you follow outlinks for the webpages or does the size of your index remain constant? 50M urls is not very much so I don't expect that ES would be super busy.

Have you tried using the AggregationSpout instead? The CollapsingSpout is pretty new + it is probably better to use it with a bucket size of 1 as I think it emits a separate query for each bucket.

It is difficult to tell exactly where the problem is without seeing your topology. Try to find any obvious culprits using the methods above.

Answer (score 0):

Julien, many thanks for the feedback. I changed my spout to AggregationSpout and imported your dashboards into Kibana.

I did a test with aggregationSpout->partitioner->dummyIndexer->statusUpdater to confirm that my spout is able to emit as a needed and it is ok (roughly 0.3 M tuples/min which is basically twice what I'm targeting for my whole topology 10 M tuples/hour).

I'm still not satisfied by the performances of the fetching though. It's very unstable in the sense of the highly fluctuating number of active threads, number of queues and queue sizes. And I have the feeling that when I increase too much the total number of threads (several thousands) the the fetcher loses the grip somehow.

From your experience, what would be the maximum number of threads you would allow per fetcher instance? And since only one instance of the fetcher is required per worker, do you see any problems wrt launching several workers to have concurrent fetchers?

Comment: any luck with the suggestions below?

Comment: Hi Julien. In fact our bottleneck might be on the central DNS server of the cluster where our node sits. Apparently the crawler puts too much pressure on the DNS server and as a preventive action they drop DNS packets.

Comment: With that respect, is there a way to bypass the default DNS server within storm-crawler?

Comment: Depends on the protocol implementation. OKHTTP provides an interface of DNS (see https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/Dns.html ). However the usual way of doing is to configure the DNS at the system level with a local DNS cache and forwarding to e.g. Google's DNS service.

Comment: so is it definitely a problem with the DNS resolution?
You could implement a protocol implementation using Vert.x - it has its own address resolver instead of the JVM built-in blocking resolver, see 
http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_host_name_resolution